# C++ STL alogrithm like 'comm' utility

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, comm

Can someone point me, please, if where is some algorithms within STL to compute  difference and intersection per one call in manner of unix comm utility?

```
int main()  
{  
 //For example we have two sets on input
 std::set<int>a = { 1 2 3 4 5 };  
 std::set<int>b = { 3 4 5 6 7 };  

 std::call_some_func(a, b, ... );
 //So as result we need obtain 3 sets  
 //x1 = {1, 2}  // present in a, but absent in b (difference)  
 //x2 = {3, 4, 5} // present on both sets (intersection)  
 //x3 = {6, 7} // present in b, but absent in a  
}
```

My current implementation uses 2 calls of 'std::set_difference' and one call of 'std::set_intersection'.

Comment: There is no single function to do that, you'd have to call the three functions you mentioned, or write something yourself

Comment: @Sergey Zhukov Write a wrapper for the three calls.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is probably a reasonably efficient implementation:

Features:

a) operates in linear time.

b) works with all ordered container types for input and all iterator types for output.

c) only requires `operator<` to be defined on the contained type, as per stl algorithms on sorted ranges.

```
template<class I1, class I2, class I3, class I4, class ITarget1, class ITarget2, class ITarget3>
auto comm(I1 lfirst, I2 llast, I3 rfirst, I4 rlast, ITarget1 lonly, ITarget2 both, ITarget3 ronly)
{
    while (lfirst != llast and rfirst != rlast)
    {
        auto&& l = *lfirst;
        auto&& r = *rfirst;
        if (l < r) *lonly++ = *lfirst++;
        else if (r < l) *ronly++ = *rfirst++;
        else *both++ = (++lfirst, *rfirst++); 
    }

    while (lfirst != llast)
        *lonly++ = *lfirst++;

    while (rfirst != rlast)
        *ronly++ = *rfirst++;
}
```

example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

/// @pre l and r are ordered
template<class I1, class I2, class I3, class I4, class ITarget1, class ITarget2, class ITarget3>
auto comm(I1 lfirst, I2 llast, I3 rfirst, I4 rlast, ITarget1 lonly, ITarget2 both, ITarget3 ronly)
{
    while (lfirst != llast and rfirst != rlast)
    {
        auto&& l = *lfirst;
        auto&& r = *rfirst;
        if (l < r) *lonly++ = *lfirst++;
        else if (r < l) *ronly++ = *rfirst++;
        else *both++ = (++lfirst, *rfirst++); 
    }

    while (lfirst != llast)
        *lonly++ = *lfirst++;

    while (rfirst != rlast)
        *ronly++ = *rfirst++;
}

int main()  
{  
 //For example we have two sets on input
 std::set<int>a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  
 std::set<int>b = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };  

std::vector<int> left;
std::set<int> right;
std::unordered_set<int> both;

comm(begin(a), end(a),
        begin(b), end(b),
        back_inserter(left),
        inserter(both, both.end()),
        inserter(right, right.end()));
 //So as result we need obtain 3 sets  
 //x1 = {1, 2}  // present in a, but absent in b (difference)  
 //x2 = {3, 4, 5} // present on both sets (intersection)  
 //x3 = {6, 7} // present in b, but absent in a  

    std::copy(begin(left), end(left), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::copy(begin(both), end(both), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::copy(begin(right), end(right), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

example output (note that the 'both' target is an unordered set):

```
1, 2, 
5, 3, 4, 
6, 7,
```

Comment: It's look like it's  good  idea to  commit proposition to standardization committee about inclusion of this implementation/algorithm to STL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single function to do that, you'd have to call the three functions you mentioned, or write something yourself. That being said, here's my attempt, though I'm not sure it's going to be any faster than the three step method you've already described

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

template <typename T>
void partition_sets(std::set<T> const& a,
                    std::set<T> const& b,
                    std::set<T>& difference_a,
                    std::set<T>& difference_b,
                    std::set<T>& intersection)
{
    std::set_intersection(begin(a), end(a),
                          begin(b), end(b),
                          std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));

    std::copy_if(begin(a), end(a), std::inserter(difference_a, difference_a.begin()), [&intersection](int i)
    {
        return intersection.find(i) == intersection.end();  
    });

    std::copy_if(begin(b), end(b), std::inserter(difference_b, difference_b.begin()), [&intersection](int i)
    {
        return intersection.find(i) == intersection.end();  
    });
}
```

Running your example

```
int main()  
{  
    //For example we have two sets on input
    std::set<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  
    std::set<int> b = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };  

    std::set<int> x1;
    std::set<int> x2;
    std::set<int> x3;
    partition_sets(a, b, x1, x2, x3);

    std::cout << "a - b\n\t";
    for (int i : x1)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "b - a\n\t";
    for (int i : x2)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "intersection\n\t";
    for (int i : x3)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

produces the output

```
a - b
    1 2 
b - a
    6 7 
intersection
    3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write a wrapper for the three calls of the algorithms.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include<tuple>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
auto comm(const std::set<T> &first, const std::set<T> &second)
{
    std::tuple<std::set<T>, std::set<T>, std::set<T>> t;

    std::set_difference(first.begin(), first.end(),
        second.begin(), second.end(),
        std::inserter(std::get<0>(t), std::get<0>(t).begin()));

    std::set_intersection(first.begin(), first.end(),
        second.begin(), second.end(),
        std::inserter(std::get<1>(t), std::get<1>(t).begin()));

    std::set_difference(second.begin(), second.end(),
        first.begin(), first.end(),
        std::inserter(std::get<2>(t), std::get<2>(t).begin()));

    return t;
}

int main()
{
    std::set<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::set<int> b = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

    auto t = comm(a, b);

    for (auto x : std::get<0>(t)) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto x : std::get<1>(t)) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto x : std::get<2>(t)) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
```